# More touch screen support for ubuntu 15 desktop

Tags: touchscreen

Just installed ubuntu 15 on my asus ep121. Touch screen works. Yeah hoo.  Can we install more touch-tablet features?

The on screen keyboards pops up for many ubuntu apps but not internet browser text fields.  Suggestions?